# Only Getting a Static String for OnValueChanged of InputField

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field

I have an InputField and I'm targeting my "FindSoftware" function for OnValueChanged but it won't pass the string of the InputField. I can manually type what it will pass beside where I select which function to call ("This_is_Static_Boo..." in the example below), but that's no good since I want the text I am currently typing into it. How do I make it dynamic?

```cs
public void FindSoftware(String s)
{
    Debug.Log("Updated string = " + s); // Always blank or whatever I statically tell it to be
}
```

[image]

Comment: Because the value has changed. Just read the new value

Comment: Post the function you are trying to call OnValueChanged

Comment: Does that help and/or clarify?

Comment: As mentioned you just need to read the new value from the input box.. if you read https://answers.unity.com/questions/1649522/inputfield-onvaluechanged.html you will see that this doesnt seem to work as people expect eg it doesnt send the changed text by default.    Just read the field.Text ti get the value, but it will do it each time it changes.

Comment: @BugFinder no, it needs to pass it along itself. My function wouldn't have any way of knowing which field was calling it so I can't simply get the text from InputField.text. I don't have a handle to the InputField. As in the answer below, it can pass the string directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of callbacks for [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html)s

> When configuring a `UnityEvent` in the Inspector there are two types of function calls that are supported:
>
> - **Static**. Static calls are preconfigured calls, with preconfigured values that are set in the UI. This means that when the callback is invoked, the target function is invoked with the argument that has been entered into the UI.
> - **Dynamic**. Dynamic calls are invoked using an argument that is sent from code, and this is bound to the type of `UnityEvent` that is being invoked. The UI filters the callbacks and only shows the dynamic calls that are valid for the `UnityEvent`.

So when setting up your method call just make sure you select the one from the `Dynamic` section on the top where all callable methods are listed that take `string` (or the given type(s)) as a parameter(s).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! As a point of clarification for future viewers, I had to select my particular class object in the list rather than generic "GameObject" and sure enough, there was a "Dynamic string" section at the top. I searched for my function name bottom up and found the static one and thought I was done rather than noting the Dynamic section with the same function listed again!